# How to pass horizontal scrolling through a UICollectionView and it's cell?

Tags: ios, objective-c, uicollectionview, uicollectionviewcell

I've got a UICollectionView which, at the top, has a clear cell to show a UIScrollView below. The UIScrollView should pan left/right. How to I pass the left/right scrolling down to the UIScrollView, whilst still allowing up/down scrolling on the whole UICollectionView?

```
-------------------  < Clear cell in clear UICollectionView
|                 |    with clear background.
|        A        |    UIScrollView with 3 pages is behind
|                 |    the UICollectionView. Allow scroll left/right
|       ...       |    for pages and up/down for table.
-------------------
|                 |
|        B        |  
-------------------  < Normal UICollectionView cells
|        |        |
|        |        |
|   C    |   D    |
|        |        |
-------------------
```